# Case insensitive comparison in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have code in TCL:

```
set a 1
set b 0
set c "Start"
if { $a == 1 && ($b == 1 || $c == "Start") } {
    puts Works
}
```

I want to make  `$c == "Start"` to check for case insensitive `Start`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`string compare`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.htm#M5):

> ```
> string compare ?-nocase? ?-length int? string1 string2
> ```
>
> Perform a character-by-character comparison of strings `string1` and `string2`. Returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`, depending on whether `string1` is lexicographically less than, equal to, or greater than `string2`. If `-length` is specified, then only the first length characters are used in the comparison. If `-length` is negative, it is ignored. If `-nocase` is specified, then the strings are compared in a case-insensitive manner.

So, if it returns `0`, then you have `$c` exactly equal to `String`.

```
set a 1
set b 0
set c "Start"
if { $a == 1 && ($b == 1 || [string compare -nocase $c "Start"] == 0) } {
    puts Works
}
```

The `-nocase` switch ensures it uses case insensitive comparison as the documentation mentions.

---

An alternative could be to make `$c` to a uniform case and use `Start` with a uniform case too. For instance, you could convert everything to lowercase:

```
set a 1
set b 0
set c "Start"
if { $a == 1 && ($b == 1 || [string tolower $c] == "start") } {
    puts Works
}
```

Or uppercase...

```
set a 1
set b 0
set c "Start"
if { $a == 1 && ($b == 1 || [string toupper $c] == "START") } {
    puts Works
}
```

---

Another alternative could be with `regexp`, if you don't mind 'exploring' that area.

```
set a 1
set b 0
set c "Start"
if { $a == 1 && ($b == 1 || [regexp -nocase -- {^Start$} $c]) } {
    puts Works
}
```

`regexp` returns `1` for a match and `0` for a non-match. The `^` and `$` ensure that the whole `Start` is matched against the `$c` variable. Conclusion, if `$c` is the same as `Start`, you get `1`.

Comment: Sorry. I think I did not explain correctly. I meat that I need $c == "Start" to be true in case $c equals Start, start, sTart, StarT etc. "Start" can be in any case to be $c == "Start" condition true.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very nice explanation. Both examples are working fine :)

Comment: If we're exhausting all possibilities: `regexp {(?i)^start$} $c`

Comment: `string equals -nocase` would bear mentioning too.

Comment: To expand on @DonalFellows's comment: the sub-command is `equal`, not `equals`. As in `if { [string equal -nocase $c "Start"] } { ... }`.

Comment: @TripeHound Nice catch there